# How to specify the Docker version in the Azure pipeline?

Tags: linux, git, azure, docker, pipeline

We use the Azure pipeline to deploy the React app.
Today pipeline fails and we noticed that the Docker version is upgraded.
This is the Docker version with success.

[image]

This is the Docker version when the pipeline fails.

[image]

Below is the snnipet of azure-pipelines.yml

```
trigger:
  - develop

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Build Tool Versions:"
      echo "Docker:"
      docker version
      echo "Yarn:"
      yarn version
      echo "gulp"
      gulp -v
      echo "npm"
      npm -version
      echo "node"
      node -v
    displayName: "Build Tool Versions"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can install your preferred version of Docker to the agent e.g. by using the [DockerInstaller@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-installer-v0?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) task. Versions installed to Microsoft-hosted agents are updated automatically and the included software & versions can be found [here](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md).